# Tell me how to display a variable not in span, but in input with this code

Tags: javascript, html

Tell me how to display a variable not in span, but in input with this code.

```
$(function(){
    $('#main input:radio').on("change", function(){
         var summ = 18900;
        $('#main input:radio:checked').each(function(index, element){
            var add = parseInt($(element).val(), 10); 
            if(!isNaN(add))
                summ += add;
        });
        $("#result span").text(summ);   
    })   
})  

<div class="result d-flex justify-content-center  md-auto" id="result">
<span>18900</span> руб.
<input type="text" id="result" value="18900">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should be the only element with the 'result' value in it's id property.
If you will do so, you will be able to use js `document.getElementById('result')` to get the input element, and then set it's 'value' property
(e.g. `document.getElementById('result').value = sum;`)
You can also use jQuery format
(e.g. `$('#result').val(sum);`)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.js:102)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

Comment: yeap, i find id #result and delete